# Stack sparse matrices along new axis with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have derived `d` sparse matrices `m[d]` of size `(n, n)` each, and I would like to stack them along a new axis in order to build a sparse matrix of size `(n, n, d)`.

I tried building this stacked matrix with `np.stack([m[i] for i in range(d)], axis=-1)` but this yields a `numpy.ndarray` of size `d` and not a sparse matrix (in such format, I can't use `scipy.sparse.save_npz`, which is what I ultimately want to do). `scipy.sparse` only comes with `vstack` and `hstack`, none of which suits my need here.

Is there a way to build such a matrix?

Is there a way to build a sparse matrix with more than two axis at all?

Notes:

- All sparse matrices have the same number of stored elements `m[d]`, and these elements have the same coordinates in the matrix, so stacking them should be straightforward.
- To give some context, I encountered this problem trying to compute the gradient of a function `f` defined on a mesh surface. This function associates each vertex `i` of the mesh surface with a vector `f(i)` of size `d`. All edges `(i,j)` can be stored in a sparse matrix of size `(n, n)`. Finally, each matrix `m[d]` contains the gradient along the `d`th dimension for each edge `(i, j)` of the mesh.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` only creates 2d arrays, like the `np.matrix` subclass.  Historically sparse matrices were developed for large linear algebra problems (e.g. finite difference/element).  You could make a sparse (d*n, d*n) matrix with the the (n,n) matrices laid out on the diagonal.  There may be a sparse function that does that, `bmat` or some variation.

Comment: It's `sparse.block_mat` that creates a block diagonalmatrix. (read its code).